# IQueryable<Comments> GetComments: show comments with product details

Tags: c#, asp.net, join, webforms, iqueryable

I am creating a web form app that allows a user to look at a list of products and then each products individual details.  So far the ProductDetails.aspx is showing the Product Image, description and price.  I have created a separate table from my products table for commenting (comments table).  I want to give the user the ability to log in and comment on the products in their details page.  I also want all of those comments to show up anytime the ProductDetails are shown. Here is my query to show the product details, to give you an idea of how it is written thus far.

```
public IQueryable<Product> GetProduct([QueryString("productID")] int? productId)
    {
        var _db = new Critic.Models.ProductContext();
        IQueryable<Product> query = _db.Products;

        if (productId.HasValue && productId > 0)
        {
            query = query.Where(p => p.ProductID == productId);
        }
        else
        {
            query = null;
        }
        return query;
    }
```

I want to use IQueryable with Comments, creating a GetComments Method that where I can join the two tables by their corresponding keys.  I am not sure how to do this.  If any can show some examples of how to get me on my way, I would appreciate it.

```
public IQueryable<Comments> GetComments([QueryString("commentID")] int? commentId)
{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve this by one request to your database rather than get the comments separately. The only thing that you need to handle is because you need to join your product and its comments together you might end up having one repeated product for each of its comments then on your .aspx page you only need to show the selected product once and loop the rest of the comments on your page.

> ```
> public IQueryable<Product> GetProductDetails([QueryString("productID")] int? productId)
> {
>     if (productId.HasValue && productId > 0)
>     {
>        using (var context = new Critic.Models.ProductContext()){
>           var product= from p in context.Products
>               join pc in context.ProductComments p.ProductId equals pc.ProductId
>               where p.ProductId == productId
>               select new Product { 
>                        ProductId = p.ProductId, 
>                        CommentId = c.CommentId,
>                        ProductName = p.ProductName, 
>                        CommentDesc = c.CommentDesc
>                      };
>            return product;
>        }
>     }
>     else
>         return null;
> }
> ```

hope it gives you a clue.

Comment: Why does the OP need to have a join table?  Join tables are for M:M relationships, and this seems a classic 1 (on the Product side) to Many (on the Comments side)?

Comment: Thanks @JimMSDN for mentioning it, there was an extra join on the code above that I've updated it. the remaining join only is for the rest of the product details in the Product table, so it's not only for comments otherwise using a ProductId to get the comments would be enough.